# My Magnific popup is not working with quickphp

Tags: php, image-gallery, magnific-popup

I'm totally new in website development and as my first experiment I'm working with website to replace my company's old site (if success). 
Have done pritty much allready but I really want to have this popup image gallery to work with Magnific popup for the responsiveness.

I have setup a local server with QuickPhp for development as I don't have server for my website yet. 
Eventhough my site is working when tested in CodePen but not on my Quickphp server.

I made sort of gallery site that contains images that is supposed to open to popup for larger view and to zoom closer if wanted. The popup itself will work but some of code doesn't work. In example: 
-not showin close button. 
 
-not closing popup when clicking background. 
 
-no animation when popup opens.
 
this all works with the same code tested on the CodePen-site though.

Magnific popup JS and the CSS codes I copied from the [Build tool](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#mfp-build-tool)(to the folder within the sites .php)
They are included to .php page with script. CSS in the **head** and the JS in the **footer**. JQuery is from google https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js

For now I would need answears to theese Questions:
 
1. Is it possible that the problem is within the QuickPhp-server setup of mine? If It doesn't fully support jquery in local setup?
 
2. What else could be wrong?

If needed I can put the codes here later.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the code allthough. I implemented the codes from the Maqnific website again and red the documentation over 5 times. I also noticed that the included stylesheet files needed to be linked from the website's root folder exactly as shown on the Macnific guide.

If anyone is having similar problem I suggest to keep on reading and searching. Taking a brake for day or two makes a differens in perspective too. Some time apart of the project helps to notice things that you might not have seen before. Especially checking the code for incorrections is a bitch.
 Just yesterday I found a typo in my media query meta tag that was making my site not to change styling when viewport size changes. The typo was from 2 weeks ago. max-device-width was written as max-divice-width.